# Cannot find SQL server 2012 configuration tools

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I upgraded my OS from MS windows 8.1 to 10. Now I cannot connect to the server with my working databases and I cannot find the configuration tools to start the server again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Run command,type below and press enter..

```
SQLServerManager11.msc--for sql 2012  
SQLServerManager12.msc--for sql 2014
SQLServerManager13.msc--for sql 2016
```

Hope this helps